# how can i search for a file by typing a part of its name?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a search bar that can search for files in a folder (songs) 
and I want to type half the name of the song to make it show up or probably provide a link to it
(like typing "he" and it will show results like "hello" and "hey")
is there any way I can take my input and search for it in the file names

I tried searching for the full file name but then it's just useless

So you know when you type in something in google and it attempts to complete it for you, I want to type in that part of a name then the program searches for it between the files then shows me the matching results

Comment: You just do a `LIKE %he%` query in SQL. You'll need AJAX to do your POST if you want it to update in real time though.

Comment: @ObsidianAge OP doesn't seem to use any SQL though, he wants to "_search for files in a folder_"

Comment: What's your current code?

Comment: Private use case or public?  Server environment?  How many songs all in all approx?

Comment: I think you meant that use ajax in this function $('input').keyup(){ then send request with ajax}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be to use jQuery Autocomplete:

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

1) Use PHP on server side to create an array of the filenames in the directory:

```
$filenames = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..')); //replace $path with your directory path
```

2) Then initialize the autocomplete widget on the input element. Assuming the input element has an id of 'autocomplete'

```
$( "input#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: <?php echo json_encode($filesnames); ?>
});
```

I have not tested the above code, but it should point you in the right direction.

If you have never used jQuery before, it is as simple as including a  tag in your php/html file. Read more about jQuery here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: well i guess if php can't do it without another language then i'll stick to using another language thanks for your help as i have problem with my sql server

Comment: im getting there i just need to know how can i add " to a variable in php then i    can post the final code

Answer (score 0):

and finally i've put everything together here is the code :

```
<?php


$dir = "../../resources/SdbM/";

$filenames = scandir($dir);

$no = array('.', '..');

$fc = array_diff($filenames , $no);


foreach ($fc as $a){
    $ds = '"' . $a . '",' . $ds;
}




?>
<html>
  <script src="jq.js"></script>
  <script src="jqwidget.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
    var Tags = [
    <?php echo $ds ?>
    ];
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: Tags
});
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<form action="muzik.php" method="post">
<input type="text" value="" id="autocomplete" name="search" placeholder="Search"/>
<input type="submit" value="&nbsp; Search &nbsp;" name="btn" class="btn"/>

</html>
```

note that im using both jquery and jquery widget
you can get the script from the example in [here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

thanks to @thewoodcutter for his help